# How to click on particular email

Tags: selenium, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRDXQ.png)

I have try
//driver.findElementByClassName("ng-binding").click();

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Please Confirm your email address to continue']")).click();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly and follow it in all future post. Don't add screenshots of code. its makes difficult  to reproduce the case. Instead add code as part of post

Comment: Also if any answer to your post works for you do accept it by clicking on hollow tick beside answer. Its a way of appreciating person who took his time to answer your question it also directs other community members to the right answer

Comment: @Ganesh Can you share what error you got ? Also there is no title attribute for the <a> tag you are trying to click (Not visible in image at-least). Also it always a better idea to share Page link or raw HTML rather than snippet.

Comment: https://www.mailinator.com/v3/index.jsp?zone=public&query=testclient#/#inboxpane

invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no  tag or you misspelled something inside the sentence between ''. You don't have to use entire sentence to find this element.

Try  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Confirm your email']")).click();` or any partial String inside '' quotes, which will determine exactly one element on site.